# Instantclick running functions more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pushstate, pjax

I'm using http://instantclick.io which is a jQuery plugin for pjax, however I'm getting some strange problems with my scripts. I've moved bits around so that scripts which did run on `$(document).ready(function(){` now run on `InstantClick.on('change', function(){` but I still get random problems when I browse through my website.

I was starting to get a feeling that the code is being run more than once, for example when I click on a button, the code it should run was happening more than once. So I stuck this piece of code in my js file just to see what was going on:

```
$(document).click(function(){
    console.log('click');
});
```

So whenever, I click on anything in the page, I'll get a console log. On initial load of a page, I get the console log once per click. Then when I navigate to a different page, I get two console logs per click, then three logs on the third page I visit etc. So it seems that the InstantClick is caching the js file and running the scripts every time a page is loaded.

I tried putting the `data-no-instant` attribute on the script tag where the js file is included, but this breaks my code completely.

Hope someone can help!

Comment: It sounds like you might need an unbind function first.

Comment: Can you post more of your code, or create a jsfiddle? Thanks

Comment: try to change the order of your `InstantClick.init` and InstantClick `change` event listener, so the listener will be after the init call.